# edge.create want trigger on like box

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, sdk, facebook-like

I have a like button that works perfectly. But when i try to add callback to the like-box it wont trigger. I read on a stack topic that says its a bug(?) and i tried allot, but i cant find it out.

The code i use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nb_NO/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=163145893868097";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="292" data-height="200" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

EDIT:

And the callback within the javascript code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check and track this bug on Facebook Developers:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/508219649233845